# multiple protractor tests using promise value with loop concept

Tags: protractor

I want to generate multiple protractor tests using promise value with loop concept, Please give me a solution .

```
var rowNumber = function call;
rowNumber.then(function(resultTC){`enter code here`
         for (var i = 1; i < parseInt(resultTC); i++) {
                    it('should work for ' + i, function (done) {
                        console.log("welcome");
                    });
           };
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate more tests passing different data with data parametrization, I don't know why You need looping.